Override collection name in @Agregation for tests
I have a Spring Data repository that receives the collection name from a variable in my application.yaml. It works great except that I want to do some integration tests, and to prevent issues with a shared mongo db I'm renaming the collection from <collection_name> to <collection_name>_dev1, mostly works, but for the queries that are defined with aggregation pipelines with operations like lookup or graphLookup the 'from' field is not parameterizable, doesn't receive regular expressions, is there a way to override these fields and keep using MongoRepositories?
@Document(collection= "#{environment.getProperty('collection.users')}")
public class User {
....

public interface AccountsRepository extends MongoRepository<User,String> {
...
@Agregation(pipeline = "{$lookup: {from: 'AppUsers', localField: 'userName', foreignField: 'parentUser' ...
List<User> getUserAccounts(String userName);
...

this doesn't work
...
@Agregation(pipeline = "{$lookup: {from: '#{environment.getProperty('collection.users')}', localField: userName, ...
List<Accounts> getUserAccounts(String userName);
...

I want my tests to work with something like this
@SpringBootTest(properties = { "collection.users=AppUsers_Dev"})
public class UserRepositoryIntegrationTests{
...

